# Issue when running gcloud (Google Cloud SDK) in Cloud Shell

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-shell

When I try running `gcloud` command in a Cloud Shell, I get the following error:

**Command**:

```
user@one-more-gcp-test:~$ gcloud help
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 88, in <module>
    main()
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py", line 64, in main
    import traceback
ImportError: No module named traceback
```

I created a new GCP project and activated Cloud Shell and tried running the same command again but I get the same error.

Comment: Are you able to use other gcloud commands as 'gcloud config list'? Have you [updated SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/)? Which OS are you using?

Comment: When you say cloud shell, you mean the one you start from gcp console?

Comment: @Oliver I am using Cloud Shell (https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/) from GCP Console

Comment: @Watacroft No I cannot use any gcloud commands. I am using Cloud Shell (https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/). From what I know cloud shell comes installed with Cloud SDK.

Comment: Yes, it installed by default, but you can update it, by using [gcloud components update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update)

Comment: Python's traceback module has been around forever so this import error doesn't make sense, it is surely hiding the real issue. Maybe your python installation has been damaged? Start a Python shell and import traceback manually, does it work?

Comment: @Watacroft I get the following error still:

    `ImportError: No module named traceback`

Comment: @Oliver it works fine when I start a Python shell and import traceback manually

Comment: Somehow the python path is incorrect, the module gcloud.py is being called from a zipped file or venv or something weird. I would delete this question and start from scratch with a new question, listing the *exact* set of steps to reproduce the problem on your account, don't leave anything out just because "it's obvious". If there is anything that looks funny with the steps, we might see it. Otherwise, it's a case for google cloud support ticket.